# Pass private key via kvm

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I for some reason am not able to access my server via SSH. However I can connect via my KVM. But I have disabled password access so cannot use sudo at all.

Is it possible to pass the privatekey as a string... Maybe its a crazy idea, but with access I could remove the public key and generate a new key.

But as it stands, I cannot do anything with my server.

Comment: What kind of VM you using ? qcow2-files can be used like devices, for example. Or maybe you can `su -` into root ?

Comment: Thanks Mario, sadly if I try `su -` it asks me for a password. Which I don't have.
However its a ubuntu 20.04 VM. Sorry I should have said

Comment: I can assume you using a type 1 hypervisor cause of KVM, but what kind of files you created or what software you used to create that VM ? If you have created images via `qemu` I can tell you how to get to your VM partitions without even starting it. But if you created the VM an other way maybe some1 else can help you there.

Comment: There is no way to change private keys in `/etc/ssh.d/` without root access. The only way to change private keys is in `~/.ssh/`. An other way around is what I wrote before.

Comment: I will find out about the VM as it is a hosted VM via streamline.net. As for SSH yes :D However I was hopeful that I could manually type my private key into the KVM kind of `like   login: root
password: privatekey --- etc etc etc ----` Wishful thinking of course :D